# Graph search query: total results differs between pages

Tags: search, search-results, query, sorting

I'm encountering this issue: calling the **POST /v1.0/search/query Graph API**, with the following body:

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": ["listItem"],
            "query": {"queryString": "*"},
            "from": 0,
            "size": 20,
            "fields": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the following response:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "searchTerms": [],
            "hitsContainers": [
                {
                    "hits": [// 20 list items]
                    "total": 66,
                    "moreResultsAvailable": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The query matches 66 items in total and I get 20 elements for page 1 ("from":0).

Because we have other results to see, let's get items for page 2 ("from":20):

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": ["listItem"],
            "query": {"queryString": "*"},
            "from": 20,
            "size": 20,
            "fields": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Now in the response I get a different number of total items:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "searchTerms": [],
            "hitsContainers": [
                {
                    "hits": [// 20 list items]
                    "total": 55,  // why?! it must be the same for every page!
                    "moreResultsAvailable": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Unlike [what said in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/searchhitscontainer?view=graph-rest-1.0) total should return the amount of items retrieved by the query, independently from pagination.
I get 55 items also for page 3.

If I set a page of 100 items ("size":100), I get 55 items in total field, so I guess this is the correct total amount.

Nevertheless I **always** get total to 55 if I add a sortProperties field in my request, also for page 1:

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": ["listItem"],
            "query": {"queryString": "*"},
            "from": 0,
            "size": 20,
            "sortProperties": [
                {
                    "name": "Created",
                    "isDescending": true
                }
            ]
            "fields": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Do you have any idea of why I have this behaviour?

Thank you.